# Batch file restart spooler and auto confirm a separate service

Tags: batch-file, service, spooler

I'm trying to write a batch file for restarting the print spooler at our library.  I thought I could get away with,

```
@echo off
NET stop spooler
NET start spooler
```

However, it then asks Y/N if I want to restart the "LPT:One Print Service" (lptclient) and I need it to auto confirm yes.

How would I go about setting that up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a *undocumented* parameter that works with net commands, `/y` or `/yes` which bypasses the prompt. So in your case it would be: `NET stop spooler /y`

Big thanks to [imtheman](https://superuser.com/users/87813/imtheman) for pointing this out on [superuser](https://superuser.com/); [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1264254/pipe-y-into-net-stop-on-windows).

Comment: That worked pretty well.  The only downside is that it doesn't restart the LPT service.  I was able to remedy that by tossing "NET start lptclient" at the end.  And apparently it only works when run as administrator.  So I made a shortcut, set the shortcut to "Run as administrator," and tossed it in the startup folder.  

Many thanks!

Comment: @CoriG Many windows services require administrative permissions when dealing with the `NET stop` and the `NET start` command. Glad your issue was resolved.